# Spliting a file to parse text. Regex or other method

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text file that has multiple lines and each line has time stamp. I want to split it at certain date and than run a regular Regex.Matches for a word.

So I have a DateTime Variable that is called

```
var date;

While(!reader.EndOfStream)
{

//need to split the document at certain date maybe Regex.Split and save it as newData

var matches=Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(newData), someWord);

}
```

I dont know how to split the document at certain point using Regex or some other way. How can I go about splitting it?

```
Portion of datafile is 

2013-03-03 19:08:27    Truck 2012 Toyota
2013-03-03 19:08:44    car 2008   Honda
2013-03-03 19:08:55    car 2011   Ford
2013-03-03 19:09:21    car 2005   Nissan
2013-03-03 19:08:29    car 2003   Cadillac
2013-03-03 19:08:32    car 2009   Ford
2013-03-03 19:08:52    car 2007   Suburban";
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? If its normalized in anyway it should be very easy.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an list of anonymous objects based on the data in the text file , then you can query the list depending on what you are after

Example:

```
   // create anonymous objects
   var myData = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\test.txt")
       .Select(line => line.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
       .Select(splits => new 
       {
           Date = DateTime.Parse(splits[0] + " " + splits[1]),
           Make = splits[2].Trim(),
           Year = int.Parse(splits[3].Trim()),
           Model = splits[4].Trim()
       });

   // find all "Ford" at my date
   var results = myData.Select(x => x.Date == myDate && x.Model == "Ford");
```

**Note:** You will probably want to add some error handling to the anonymous object creation (int.TryParse, DateTime.TryParse) as your text file may not be consistant.